# Is frame rate near the edge of the eye different than that in the center?

Tags: visible-light, vision

This is actually a biology question, but it has to do with frame rates, so I posted it here.

Suppose, that you are looking at the lightbulb. Most of the lightbulbs nowadays run on alternating current, let's say on $50\ Hz$. When you look directly at the lightbulb, you see a steady intensity because frame rate of the eye is around $25 \ Hz$. But when you look slightly away, you can see some blinking.

Is the frame rate of the eye near the edge different? Is so, is it bigger or smaller? I believe, that it is bigger.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to a biology or neurology site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to the extent that "frame rate" has meaning in the realm of neuro-optics.  So far as I know, our model of how the brain converts signals from the retina into image information is still changing and not fully understood.   We do know that the "average person" perceives smooth motion for static image update rates greater than about 15-20 fps (movie or video screen update rates).  It does seem that neural recognitin of image changes in the edges of the field of view is apparently more sensitive than in the fovea (both in speed and magnitude).

I would recommend you ask a mod to migrate this to a biology or neurology site, as it is more appropriate to your interest.  They do deal with 'frame rate' as well as other "physics" terms like 'wavelength' and 'rate of change' :-) .

Comment: Nice answer. Approved.